# Browse all the rows and columns that contain a zero

Tags: stata

Suppose I have 100 variables named `ID, var1, var2, ..., var99`. I have 1000 rows. I want to *browse* all the rows and columns that contain a `0`.

I wanted to just do this:

```
browse ID, var* if var* == 0
```

but it doesn't work. I don't want to hardcode all 99 variables obviously.

I wanted to essentially write an if like this:

```
gen has0 = 0
forvalues n = 1/99 {
  if var`n' does not contain 0 {
    drop v
  } // pseudocode I know doesn't work
  has0 = has0 | var`n' == 0
}
browse if has0 == 1
```

but obviously that doesn't work.

Do I just need to reshape the data so it has 2 columns `ID, var` with 100,000 rows total?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I list negative values across my dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52951589/how-can-i-list-negative-values-across-my-dataset)

Comment: The terminology _rows_ and _columns_ is foreign to Stata. The terms are _observations_ and `variables_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My dear colleague @NickCox forces me to reply to this (duplicate) question because he is claiming that downloading, installing and running a new command is better than using *built-in* ones when you "need to select from 99 variables".

Consider the following toy example:

```
clear

input var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1 4 9 5 0
1 8 6 3 7
0 6 5 6 8
4 5 1 8 3
2 1 0 2 1
4 6 7 1 9
end

list

     +----------------------------------+
     | var1   var2   var3   var4   var5 |
     |----------------------------------|
  1. |    1      4      9      5      0 |
  2. |    1      8      6      3      7 |
  3. |    0      6      5      6      8 |
  4. |    4      5      1      8      3 |
  5. |    2      1      0      2      1 |
  6. |    4      6      7      1      9 |
     +----------------------------------+
```

Actually you don't have to download anything:

```
preserve

generate obsno = _n
reshape long var, i(obsno)

rename var value
generate var = "var" + string(_j)

list var obsno value if value == 0, noobs

  +----------------------+
  |  var   obsno   value |
  |----------------------|
  | var5       1       0 |
  | var1       3       0 |
  | var3       5       0 |
  +----------------------+

levelsof var if value == 0, local(selectedvars) clean

display "`selectedvars'"
var1 var3 var5

restore
```

This is the approach i recommended in the linked question for identifying negative values. Using `levelsof` one can do the same thing with `findname` using a *built-in* command.

This solution can also be adapted for `browse`:

```
preserve

generate obsno = _n
reshape long var, i(obsno)

rename var value
generate var = "var" + string(_j)

browse var obsno value if value == 0

levelsof var if value == 0, local(selectedvars) clean

display "`selectedvars'"

pause

restore
```

Although i do not see why one would want to `browse` the results when can simply `list` them.

---

**EDIT:**

Here's an example more closely resembling the OP's dataset:

```
clear
set seed 12345
set obs 1000

generate id = int((_n - 1) / 300) + 1

forvalues i = 1 / 100 {
    generate var`i' = rnormal(0, 150)
}

ds var*

foreach var in `r(varlist)' {
    generate rr = runiform()
    replace `var' = 0 if rr < 0.0001
    drop rr
}
```

Applying the above solution yields:

```
display "`selectedvars'"
var13 var19 var35 var36 var42 var86 var88 var90

list id var obsno value if value == 0, noobs sepby(id)

  +----------------------------+
  | id     var   obsno   value |
  |----------------------------|
  |  1   var86      18       0 |
  |  1   var19     167       0 |
  |  1   var13     226       0 |
  |----------------------------|
  |  2   var88     351       0 |
  |  2   var36     361       0 |
  |  2   var35     401       0 |
  |----------------------------|
  |  3   var42     628       0 |
  |  3   var90     643       0 |
  +----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: wildcards for bunches of variables can't be inserted in `if` qualifiers. (The `if` command is different from the `if` qualifier.)

Your question is contradictory on what you want. At one point your pseudocode has you `drop`ping variables! `drop` has a clear, destructive meaning to Stata programmers: it doesn't mean "ignore".

But let's stick to the emphasis on `browse`.

```
findname, any(@ == 0)
```

finds variables for which any value is 0. `search findname, sj` to find the latest downloadable version.

Note also that

```
findname, type(numeric)
```

will return the numeric variables in `r(varlist)` (and also a local macro if you so specify).

Then several `egen` functions compete for finding 0s in each observation for a specified *varlist*: the command `findname` evidently helps you identify which *varlist*.

Let's create a small sandbox to show technique:

```
clear
set obs 5 
gen ID = _n 
forval j = 1/5 { 
    gen var`j' = 1
}
replace var2 = 0 in 2 
replace var3 = 0 in 3 

list 

findname var*, any(@ == 0) local(which) 
egen zero = anymatch(`which'), value(0) 

list `which' if zero 

     +-------------+
     | var2   var3 |
     |-------------|
  2. |    0      1 |
  3. |    1      0 |
     +-------------+
```

So, the problem is split into two: finding the observations with any zeros and finding the observations with any zeros, and then putting the information together.

Naturally, the use of `findname` is dispensable as you can just write your own loop to identify the variables of interest:

```
local wanted 

quietly foreach v of var var* { 
    count if `v' == 0 
    if r(N) > 0 local wanted `wanted' `v' 
}
```

Equally naturally, you can `browse` as well as `list`: the difference is just in the command name.